# Linux WiFi interface very slow

Tags: wireless

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with a Panda USB WiFi interface. Until a week ago (around the time I briefly put in the interface into Monitor mode), I was getting good connection speeds to my router. Since then, however, things have slowed down a lot (from 2-3 mbps to well below 1 mbps) and I'm getting high Tx excessive retries numbers from iwconfig - even after I turned Power Management off.
There's nothing wrong with my router or ISP connection - other wireless devices are getting great speeds. 
Here's some data:

```
$ iwconfig

wlx9cefd5fe6a19  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Primus-2532"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:23:6A:78:25:34   
          Bit Rate=6.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:259421  Invalid misc:7647   Missed beacon:0
```

Any ideas? Could I have messed something up while in Monitor mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, purging and then reinstalling the wpasupplicant package fixed this problem.